# How do you convert a user entered (cin) character into ASCII code

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   char letter;

   cout << "Enter any character\n";

   cin >> letter;

   static_cast<(int)>(letter);

   cout << "Your character converted into ASCII code is " << letter << endl;

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/nIxZ2B

Comment: I've tested this, but on my IBM mainframe the results don't seem to match my ASCII chart at all.

Comment: @JerryCoffin were you looking at the hex column? Anyway, locale settings determine character encoding, there is probably a cross platform conversion function but it works for me

Comment: @user3125280: No, not hex. Hint #1: I was being facetious. Hint #2: IBM mainframes use EBCDIC, not ASCII.

Comment: you can't use static cast like that either

Comment: @JerryCoffin interesting history lesson, i never knew IBM character encoding jokes were a thing

Comment: @user3125280: Most of them really aren't very funny, but I've seen a few. They've mostly fallen out of favor as the dinosaurs who knew anything about IBM mainframes have taken to dying off...

Answer (score 4):

You had pretty much the right idea with:

```
static_cast<(int)>(letter);
```

...but you missed an important point: your cast doesn't change the original item; it produces a new item of the specified type. What you want is something more like:

```
cout << "The code for your character is " << static_cast<int>(letter) << "\n";
```

Notes:

1. No need to use parentheses inside the angle brackets of a cast.
2. It's probably best to forget that `endl` exists--I'd advise against using it (ever).

Comment: Why so categorically about std::endl?

Comment: @mexus: You nearly never want what it does, and on the rare occasion that you do, it's much better to be explicit about what you want and use: `file /* ... */ << "\n" << std::flush;` instead.

Comment: are you talking about "not flushing output too often"?

Comment: @mexus: Yes. Or or more accurately, flushing output exactly when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
char a;
cout << "Enter any key." << endl << endl;
cin >> a;
cout << "you have pressed: \'" << a << "\'" << endl << endl;
int b;
b = a;
cout << "ASCII value of the key pressed is: " << b << endl;
```

Comment: Did you read the answer posted some 9 years ago? Especially what it says about not over-using `std::endl`.